# NestJS: Cannot find module in dev mode

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

[image]

I have this error in development mode of an application with NestJS.

My configuration file is as follows:

```
export const ORM_CONFIG: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  keepConnectionAlive: true,
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'postgres',
  database: 'aimbra_education',
  schema: 'security',
  synchronize: true,
  entities: [
   --Entities
  ],
  // migrations: [__dirname + '/migration/**/*.ts'],
  // subscribers: [__dirname + '/subscriber/**/*.ts'],
};
```

I import into:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(ORM_CONFIG),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

So far I couldn't identify the error of why it works in production and doesn't work in development mode to watch my modifications.

Comment: check if paths imports have the prefix `"src/..."` if is there replace it for manually location `"../../..."`

Comment: `import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from '../../../node_modules/typeorm';` I tried to add, but it still didn't work ...

Comment: not for `node_modules`, try with yours services,controllers,modules,entities files

Comment: could you provide your `tsconfig.json` file content please ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try this:

For example when i make some file from the nestjs cli, there import his path like this:

`import { UsersService } from 'src/modules/users/users.service';`

giving the error like you.

[image]

Then when i replace the path to find it manually:

`import { UsersService } from './users.service';`

the error is fixed.
[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. But, I wonder if there is any way to change this reference? To not have to be manually importing ...